# Use google-spreadsheets with nodejs with service account?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can use a service account with nodejs in order to access at a sheet on google with google api?

I tried with the nodejs (npm) module `google-spredsheet` but when  the loadInfo() it returns always `Request failed error 404`

edit1:
ii already have a service account and the key file downloaded and in my directory.
Here's the actual script:

```
const express     = require("express"),
{GoogleSpreadsheet} = require('google-spreadsheet'),
creds             = require('./client_secret.json'),
app             = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

app.get("/google-spreadsheet", async function(req, res){
  
  // Identifying which document we'll be accessing/reading from
  
  var doc;
  
    doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs/edit#gid=0');

  // Authentication
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds); 
  
    await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
    console.log("test: "+doc.title);

});


app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('[EXPRESS] Web Server active on: ' + 8080);
});
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can I ask you about your question? 1. You have already had your service account which can use for getting and putting values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API? 2. Can you provide your current script?

Comment: yes i already have the service account. i edited the post

Comment: Thank you for your quick replying. As one more question, what version of "google-spredsheet" are you using?

Comment: i downloaded the last one: 6.14.8

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm the version you use. By the way, when I saw your script, `client_secret.json` is used. In this case, is that the credential file for the service account? I'm worry that it might be used for OAuth2. If that file is for the service account, the email of the service account is included. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Yes they are included both client_email and private_key. I tried to use oauth like google dev guide explain but it gives some error and i do not know how to solve and i'm not good for oauth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221238/discussion-between-romans-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- Your `client_secret.json` is for the service account.
- You are using "google-spreadsheet" of the latest version.
- You want to access to the Google Spreadsheet using "google-spreadsheet" with the service account.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `'1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs/edit#gid=0` is used as the Spreadsheet ID. In this case, such error occurs. I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So please modify it to `'1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs'`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs/edit#gid=0');
```

To:

```
doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs');
```

#### Note:

- When the Google Spreadsheet of `1XKcnyJkTyq15AlvhAs3V_2wnP8vgwY3mWXAijyiINVs` is not shared with the email of the service account, the service account cannot use the Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)